# Routing Errors on attempts to delete all records in a table using Rails 4 through a link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Rails 4, and am trying to delete all the assessments using a link_to helper. The pertinent code is below:

**routes.rb**

```
   resources :assessments do
     collection do
       delete :remove_all
     end
   end
```

**assessment index.html.erb**

```
 <p>To delete all assessments in one swoop, click <%= link_to 'Remove ALL Assessments', remove_all_assessments_path, method: :destroy, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

**assessments_controller.rb**

```
  def remove_all
    @assessments = Assessment.all
    @assessments.each do |assessment|
        assessment.destroy(assessment.id)
     end
    flash[:notice] = "All assessments have been deleted."
    redirect_to assessments_url
  end
```

I run `rake routes` and

```
Prefix                 Verb   URI Pattern                       Controller#Action
remove_all_assessments DELETE /assessments/remove_all(.:format) assessments#remove_all
```

**The HTML source generated for the link:**

```
<p>To delete all assessments in one swoop, click <a data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="destroy" href="/assessments/remove_all" rel="nofollow">Remove ALL Assessments</a>
```

When I click on the 'Remove All Assessments' link, I expect to have the remove_all action run in the AssessmentsController, and delete all the assessments in @assessments, then redirect me to the assessments_url. However, when I click on the 'Remove ALL Assessments', link, I am brought to the url: `http://localhost:3000/assessments/remove_all` with the error `No route matches [POST] "/assessments/remove_all"`

What gives?

Comment: `Assessment.destroy_all` is shorter

Comment: It is not just shorter! The way you delete assessments is a typical `N + 1 query`! You should certainly avoid it.

Comment: Also `destroy` method does not accept arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be 
`<p>To delete all assessments in one swoop, click <%= link_to 'Remove ALL Assessments', remove_all_assessments_path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>`

Answer (score 2):

Verb is `DELETE`, so you should use the `:delete` method in your `link_to`.

There is no method `DESTROY` in the HTTP spec.