# Unable to delete all records in Rails 4 through link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I was originally getting a routing error posted in [Routing Errors on attempts to delete all records in a table using Rails 4 through a link_to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21489136/how-do-i-delete-all-records-in-a-table-using-rails-4-through-a-link-to), and that has been resolved.

Now I am having problems with "id=remove_all" being passed. I'm using Rails 4, and am trying to delete all the assessments using a link_to helper. The pertinent code is below:

**routes.rb**

```
   resources :assessments do
     collection do
       delete :remove_all
     end
   end
```

**assessment index.html.erb**

```
 <p>To delete all assessments in one swoop, click <%= link_to 'Remove ALL Assessments', remove_all_assessments_path, method: :destroy, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

**assessments_controller.rb**

```
  def remove_all
    @assessments = Assessment.all
    @assessments.each do |assessment|
        assessment.destroy(assessment.id)
     end
    flash[:notice] = "All assessments have been deleted."
    redirect_to assessments_url
  end
```

I run rake routes and

```
Prefix                 Verb   URI Pattern                       Controller#Action
remove_all_assessments DELETE /assessments/remove_all(.:format) assessments#remove_all
```

The HTML source generated for the link:

```
<p>To delete all assessments in one swoop, click <a data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="destroy" href="/assessments/remove_all" rel="nofollow">Remove ALL Assessments</a>
```

When I click on the 'Remove All Assessments' link, I expect to have the remove_all action run in the AssessmentsController, and delete all the assessments in @assessments, then redirect me to the assessments_url. However, when I click on the 'Remove ALL Assessments', link, I am brought to the url: `http://localhost:3000/assessments/remove_all`

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in AssessmentsController#destroy
Couldn't find Assessment with id=remove_all

# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_assessment
@assessment = Assessment.find(params[:id])
end
```

The logs show:

```
Started DELETE "/assessments/remove_all" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-31 15:41:41 -0500
Processing by AssessmentsController#destroy as HTML
 Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"fooBarBaz=", "id"=>"remove_all"}
```

How do pass the collection of @assessments to the remove_all action using the Delete verb? Is this possible?

Comment: Do you have something else in your routes?

Comment: You should also have `method: :delete` instead of `method: :destroy` in the link.

Comment: Also instead of iterating over all the assessments with an each block you can just do `@assessments.destroy_all`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is Because

```
resources :assessments
```

already have route to destroy
like `/assessment/:id with method :delete`

so your `remove_all_assessments_path` will hit to that url bcoz it comes first in in your routes.rb file

To solve your problem u have to do something like this:-

```
resources :assessments, except: [:destroy] do
 collection do
   delete :remove_all
 end 
end
```

or define your remove_all_assessments url above it.

like

```
 match "/assessments/remove_all", to: "assessments#remove_all", via: [:delete], as: :remove_all_assessments
 resources :assessments do
 collection do
   delete :remove_all
 end 
end
```